# Is there an explanation for the resurrection of the Cylons?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

At first glance it's quite clear. When a Cylon dies, his (digital) consciousness is uploaded to the resurrection hub and there it is downloaded to a new body.

But on a closer look there are many open questions:

1. It seems that the range of the upload is far greater than the usual communication range of the Cylon technology.
2. If a Cylon is destroyed completely (or his head or wherever his consciousness is stored) how could it be uploaded after that? (e.g. destroyed raiders)
3. Why don't they have more resurrection hubs?
4. How could a biological Cylon be able to upload his consciousness despite of being indistinguishable from humans by medical examinations? The mechanisms for that (and by the way for interfacing with a wire in the arm) should be detectable by colonial medical technology.

And I could find probably more questions. So is there any official explanation how the resurrection works?

Comment: A fictional interpretation of quantum entanglement theory can resolve points 1, 2 and 4 (partially - doesn't answer the interface-in-the-arm part).  Quantum entanglement can be continuous (so no single upload required - its always happening as a stream), very difficult to detect if you don't share the technology base (so undetectable to the Colonials), and doesn't have to happen at faster-than-light speeds, answering the implied question of "why don't they use the same tech to communicate?"

Comment: As for 3, its implied that the technology to build it is "lost" as the Cylons need the final five to recreate it when the hub is destroyed

Answer (score 4):

The resurrection tech was coordinated by the [Resurrection Hub](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Resurrection_Hub)

From [Resurrection](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Resurrection_(RDM))

> For resurrection to occur, the dying Cylon must be close to a
>   resurrection ship or hub, otherwise his or her consciousness risks
>   being permanently lost. The transmission method of a Cylon's
>   consciousness has not been explained, but a form of wireless is
>   probable. Resurrection points identified include the Cylon homeworld,
>   the central Resurrection Hub, Resurrection Ships, and planet-based
>   facilities. A rebirthing facility may have existed on occupied
>   Caprica. Within each resurrection point is at least one rebirthing
>   tank, where a duplicate body is immersed in a thick opaque substance
>   to await download (Downloaded).

[Resurrection Ships](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Resurrection_Ship) extended the operational range of the Resurrection Hub.

In S4E9 . . .

> Once the hub is destroyed the cylons can no longer resurrect.